# How to block a DDoS attack?

Tags: ddos

My website is under a DDoS attack with bots. They are all coming in from different IPs so I can't block them all. Is it possible to make a CAPTCHA or a password just to connect to the site first for like small attacks. Maybe block IPs that connect to the site 100 times in like 30 seconds or 1 minute. Any scripts to use in .htaccess or anything just to block these bots to connect to my site.

Comment: Have you considered CloudFlare?

Comment: Yes. It affects a lot of stuff for me.

Comment: I added Cloudflare but I am still being attacked.

Comment: Did you tried the free Cloudflare or the paid Cloudflare? Take note that the free version of Cloudflare doesn't have any DDOS protection.